# how to set day number to a date variable in mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have this variable in mongo

```
var f_date = new Date();
```

and I want to modify f_date's day to 1st day, I was thinking of something like

```
f_date.setDay(1);
```

how to do that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method for that is [`setDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate):

```
f_date.setDate(1);
```